# glGetFloatv with GL_CURRENT_COLOR does not work

Tags: c, opengl, graphics, colors

I have some code that looks like this:

```
GLfloat c[4];
glGetFloatv(GL_CURRENT_COLOR, c);
```

I expect the current RGBA color to be written in array `c` after the call to `glGetFloatv`. However, the values in the array do not change at all (i.e. it contains the same garbage value both before and after the call to `glGetFloatv`).

Obviously I'm either misunderstanding the meaning of `GL_CURRENT_COLOR` (get the color that was previously set by a call to `glColor4f`) or doing something wrong...

P.S.:
Also, this procedure might be called before any calls to `glColor4f` happen, but in that case I assume it should return `(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)`, right?

**Edit:** A call to `glGetError` after trying to obtain the color returns `0`.

Comment: Perhaps it's generating an error? Do you have a valid context? Tried glGetError?

Comment: I tried printing the value of `glGetError` and it returns `0`.

Comment: Also, I do have a valid OpenGL context (the program renders a couple of things to the screen before calling this function)

Comment: This wouldn't by any chance be on Android would it? I recall reading somewhere that their glGetFloatv method was broken.

Comment: No, Windows 7 and nVidia video card

Comment: I also found a weird thing, glGetFloatv works properly in the beginning of the program. It stops working after a certain call to glEnd(). Before the call to glEnd, it returns the correct value, after the call - garbage.

Comment: Actually, I think now I understand what is going on here... The call to glGet happens between glBegin and glEnd. It looks like this command is not allowed to be between glBegin and glEnd - which is why it does not produce useful values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workin' fine here:

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    GLfloat color[4];

    glGetFloatv(GL_CURRENT_COLOR, color);
    cout << "Default color: ";
    for( size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
        cout << color[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    glColor3ub( 255,0,0 );
    glGetFloatv(GL_CURRENT_COLOR, color);
    cout << "Should be red: ";
    for( size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
        cout << color[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE);

    glutInitWindowSize(200,200);
    glutCreateWindow("Color");

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Default color: 1 1 1 1
Should be red: 1 0 0 1
```

---

> P.S.: Also, this procedure might be called before any calls to glColor4f happen, but in that case I assume it should return (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0), right?

["The initial value for the current color is (1, 1, 1, 1)."](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glColor.xml#notes)

Comment: Does this answer the question...?

Comment: I figured I could show a demonstrably correct GL command sequence so they could compare it with their code and hopefully spot the place where the two diverge.